# How to bypass Java not being able to extend from multiple classes

Tags: java, abstract-class

I think I have a design problem in my Java app, but I cannot figure out how to solve or bypass it.

Say I have an interface and an abstract class implementing it as follows:

```
public interface IntegerCollection extends Collection<Integer> {
  public int sum();     
}

public abstract class AbstractIntegerCollection
                extends AbstractCollection<Integer> implements IntegerCollection {
  public int sum() {
    // fancy code to calculate the sum of all collection members (just an example)
  }
}
```

Now I would want to make this class instantiable by using the existing implementations of Collection (e.g., LinkedList); something like this:

```
public class IntegerLinkedList extends AbstractIntegerCollection, LinkedList<Integer> {

}

IntegerCollection ic = new IntegerLinkedList();
```

However, this does not work because Java does not support extending several  classes. Also it looks quite ugly to me, as there is a mixture of hierarchies.

Of course, I could let IntegerLinkedList implement IntegerCollection instead of letting it extend AbstractIntegerCollection. But then, I would have to repeat the code for sum() in all other implementations (e.g., IntegerArrayList).

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what exactly, you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Are you using java 8 or 9? If so you could make sum() a default method of your IntegerCollection interface, then make a class both extending LinkedList<Integer> and implementing IntegerCollection.

Comment: @cppbeginner The OP wan'ts to extend from `AbstractIntegerCollection` as well!

Comment: @CKing I know, but it isn't possible to extend two classes. I'm suggesting an alternative (using an interface with default methods rather than an abstract class).

Comment: @cppbeginner What would the `sum` method in the `interface` do? It doesn't really have access to the elements of the collection to `sum` them!

Comment: @CKing I'll write an answer.

Comment: @cppbeginner The app is written in Java 7, so this would not work anyway

Comment: Why don't you just import the classes you need?

Comment: @Remirror `make this class instantiable by using the existing implementations` As in you want to do something like this? `ExistingClass obj = new MyNewClass()`?

Comment: @user3437460 No as in I do not want to reimplement LinkedList etc. but just to build my class based on existing classes (e.g., through inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly, you are trying to achieve, but rather you could implements `List` instead of extending `LinkedList`

```
public class IntegerLinkedList 
             extends AbstractIntegerCollection 
             implements List<Integer>
 {

 }
```

But, you need to implements all abstract method of `List`.

Comment: True, and also I would have to do the same again for, e.g., `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

Since java 8 it has been possible to include implementations in an interface by using the `default` keyword. Therefore you don't need `AbstractIntegerCollection` - all the common code can be put in the interface. Here is an example:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Main {

    interface IntegerCollection extends Collection<Integer> {

        default int sum() {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int a : this)
                sum += a;
            return sum;
        }
    }

    static class IntegerLinkedList extends LinkedList<Integer> implements IntegerCollection {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntegerCollection list = new IntegerLinkedList();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        System.out.println(list.sum());     // Prints 6
    }
}
```

This works, but I'm not sure it's a good idea. I'd think very carefully before extending a class like `LinkedList`. Some people also consider it an anti-pattern to extend generic classes with non-generic ones.

Another thing to be aware of is that it is not possible to write `default` methods for the methods of `Object` like `equals` and `toString` etc.

Since you are using Java 7, the above solution is not available. However, with a load of tedious forwarding methods, you can do it using composition rather than inheritance. Josh Bloch's book Effective Java gives a very good explanation of why composition is preferable anyway. Here is an (incomplete) example - you'll need to add a few more forwarding methods to avoid `UnsupportedOperationException`s when you try doing other things with the list.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    abstract static class AbstractIntegerCollection extends AbstractCollection<Integer> {

        public int sum() {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int a : this)
                sum += a;
            return sum;
        }
    }

    static class IntegerLinkedList extends AbstractIntegerCollection implements List<Integer> {

        private final List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();

        @Override
        public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
            return list.iterator();
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends Integer> c) {
            return list.addAll(index, c);
        }

        @Override
        public Integer get(int index) {
            return list.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public Integer set(int index, Integer element) {
            return list.set(index, element);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean add(Integer element) {
            return list.add(element);
        }

        @Override
        public void add(int index, Integer element) {
            list.add(index, element);
        }

        @Override
        public Integer remove(int index) {
            return list.remove(index);
        }

        @Override
        public int indexOf(Object o) {
            return list.indexOf(o);
        }

        @Override
        public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
            return list.lastIndexOf(o);
        }

        @Override
        public ListIterator<Integer> listIterator() {
            return list.listIterator();
        }

        @Override
        public ListIterator<Integer> listIterator(int index) {
            return list.listIterator(index);
        }

        @Override
        public List<Integer> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
            return list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
        }

        // More of these
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntegerLinkedList list = new IntegerLinkedList();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        System.out.println(list.sum());     // Prints 6
    }
}
```

This solution is far from perfect. For one thing, it would be better if `IntegerLinkedList` extended `AbstractList<Integer>` rather than just `AbstractCollection<Integer>`, but then you couldn't extend `AbstractIntegerCollection` too.

Comment: Good answer. But like I mentioned earlier, the OP wants to extend from `AbstractCollection`. They don't have Java 8.

Comment: Thanks, good to know this possibility exists. However, besides I use Java 7, another point of extending AbstractCollection was that I have to rewrite some of its methods such as `add()`, which should not work with default methods.

Comment: @Remirror I've extended my answer to give java 7 code. Sadly there is no short solution as far as I know.

Comment: @Remirror See my answer for a less tedious, cleaner option. I see one  more issue with this answer, `IntegerLinkedList` is not a `LinkedList` so you won't be able to access `LinkedList` specific methods using `IntegerLinkedList`.

Comment: True, but you could easily add them - just make the type of `list` a `LinkedList` and add a forwarding operation for each one. In a sense our solutions are exact inverses. My class extends `AbstractIntegerCollection `and holds a reference to a `LinkedList`, whereas your extends `LinkedList` and holds a reference to an `IntegerCollectionOperations`. This means that I'm going to need a forwarding method for each method of `LinkedList` while you'll need a forwarding method for every method of `IntegerCollectionOperations`. Since `LinkedList` has loads more methods I guess that means you win :)

Comment: @cppbeginner You did not consider another disadvantage with your solution. The `LinkedList` specific operations are not part of a contract so`IntegerLinkedList` or `LongLinkedList` are not really `LinkedList` implementations by contract and may or may not provide `LinkedList` specific forwards. That's a big one!